# Module Federation in React App (cross-origin error was thrown)

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom, webpack-module-federation

I am implementing a React microfrontend using Module Federation (1 Host and 1 child).
I am using React version 17 with "@craco/craco" version as "7.0.0"

**CHILD APP CODE BELOW**

In my child app, I have craco.config.js as below

```
module.exports = {
  plugins:[
    {
      plugin: require('./config/craco-federation')
    },
  ]
};
```

In modulefederation.config.js, I have

```
const deps = require("./package.json").dependencies;

module.exports = {
    name: "myInqMfe",
    exposes: {
        //"./MyInq": "./src/components/App.js",
      "./MyInq": "./src/components/my-inq/MyInq",
    },
    filename: "remoteEntry.js",
    shared: {},
};
```

In my index.js, I have

```
import('./bootstrap');
```

In bootstrap.jsx, I have

```
ReactDOM.render(<BootstrapApp />, document.getElementById("root"))
```

In BootstrapApp.js, I have

```
import { Route, BrowserRouter, Routes } from 'react-router-dom';
import {HashRouter as Router} from 'react-router-dom';

import App from './App';

const theme = createToolkitTheme('light');

function BootstrapApp() {
  return (
      <BrowserRouter>
        <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
          <App />
        </ThemeProvider>
      </BrowserRouter>
  );
}

export default BootstrapApp;
```

In App.js, I have

```
import { Route, Routes } from "react-router-dom";
import MyInq from "./my-inq/MyInq";

function App() {
  return (
    <>
      <div>
        {/*
        <Routes>
          <Route path="/myinq-ui" element={<MyInq />} />
        </Routes>
        */}
        <Routes>
          <Route path="/*" element={<MyInq />} />
          <Route path="/myinq-ui/*" element={<MyInq />} />
        </Routes>
      </div>
    </>
  );
}

export default App;
```

In MyInq.js,

```
export default function MyInq() {
  return (
    <>
      <span>Hello from Child App !!</span>
    </>
  );
}
```

**PARENT/HOST APP CODE BELOW**

Now, in my Host app, I have craco.config.js as

```
module.exports = {
  mode: 'development',
  devServer: {
    static: 'src',
    hot: true,
    port: 3000,
    historyApiFallback: {
      disableDotRule: true
    },
    proxy: {
      '/api/**': {
        target: {
          port: 8080
        },
        secure: false
      },
      '/actuator/**': {
        target: {
          port: 8080
        },
        secure: false
      }
    }
  },
  plugins:[
    {
      plugin: require('./config/craco-federation')
    },
  ]
};
```

craco-federation.js is exactly same as child app

In modulefederation.config.js, I have

```
const { dependencies } = require('./package.json');

module.exports = {
  name: "host",
  remotes: {
    myInqMfe: "myInqMfe@http://localhost:3001/remoteEntry.js"
  },
  filename: "remoteEntry.js",
  shared: {},
};
```

Then in index.js, I have

```
import('./bootstrap');

export { };
```

In bootstrap.jsx, I have

```
ReactDOM.render(<BootstrapApp />, document.getElementById("root"))
```

In BootstrapApp.js, I have

```
import { Route, BrowserRouter, Routes } from 'react-router-dom';
import {HashRouter as Router} from 'react-router-dom';

import App from './App';

const theme = createToolkitTheme('light');

function BootstrapApp() {
  return (
    <Router>
      <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
        <App />
      </ThemeProvider>
    </Router>
  );
}

export default BootstrapApp;
```

In App.js, I have

```
import { Route, Routes, BrowserRouter } from 'react-router-dom';
import {HashRouter as Router} from 'react-router-dom';
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';

function App() {
  return (
    <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
        <div>HOST APP: <br /></div>
        <a href="/my-inq">Link to child app</a>
        <Route exact path="/myinq-ui">
          <MyInqWrapper  />
        </Route>
        {/*
        <Routes>
          <Route path="/my-inq/*" element={<MyInqWrapper />} />
        </Routes>
        */}
    </ThemeProvider>
  );
}

export default App;
```

In MyInqWrapper.jsx, I have

```
import React from 'react';
import { Spinner } from 'reactstrap';

// @ts-ignore
// eslint-disable-next-line import/no-unresolved
const MyInq = React.lazy(() => import('myInqMfe/MyInq'))

const MyInqWrapper = ()=>{
  return(
    <div>
      <React.Suspense  fallback={<Spinner/>}>
        <MyInq />
      </React.Suspense>
    </div>
  )
};

export default MyInqWrapper;
```

Now, the issue is, I want to implement this entirely using HashRouter (i.e. both for host app and child app). But for some reason, I am getting some strange errors including strangely CORS related while trying to do that.

I would highly appreciate if the code is reviewed once to identify what I might be missing to implement Hash Routing correctly.

With the above code, that I have show, I can access http://localhost:3000/#/myinq-ui and I am able to render the child component inside the host app in the browser.

But the moment, I change from BrowserRouter to HashRouter in the child app, I start seeing issues.

The error I am seeing for the host app is as below

```
Error: A cross-origin error was thrown. React doesn't have access to the actual error object in development. See https://reactjs.org/link/crossorigin-error for more information.
```

Comment: What sorts of issues are you seeing when switching to the `HashRouter` in the child component/app? Also, it's a bit unclear if you are rendering `MyInq` directly in the parent app, or if it is actually rendering the child app's `App` component which renders another router and the `MyInq` component. Can you [edit] to clean up some of the unnecessary code and make it a more clear distinction between what is parent app and what is child app?

Comment: @DrewReese - 
For the exact error, it'll take me some time to recreate. But like I said, the errors seems totally weird including CORS error...
But yeah, I am rendering MyInq directly in the App component (via a wrapper component MyInqWrapper that I have shown)

The actual MyInq component is in the child app which renders "Hello from Child App !!"

Comment: For Host/Child app code, I have updated in the question and now marked in bold

Comment: My only initial thought was that the child app's router needs a `basename="/my-inq"` prop so that it can route/navigate correctly relative to the path it's running from, but I don't believe that would have any effect on CORS issues you are getting from the server.

Comment: yeah, for now, the child's App.js already has defined <Route path="/myinq-ui/*" element={<MyInq />} /> and I am able to navigate/render to the child component....However, I want to make it work by using HashRouter in the child app instead of the BrowserRouter

Comment: @DrewReese - I'll appreciate if you can just have a glance at the overall code (more specifically on the routing aspect) and see if you can identify any issue...

Comment: I felt like I already provided my thought on what the issue is and what to try. Specifying a `basename` prop on a router isn't the same thing as rendering route paths. Maybe the paths are fine as you have them though. I'm not very familiar with any pattern you are using though, so I don't think I can be much further help.

Comment: I have updated the actual error in the OP

Comment: Looks like the cross origin error was caused by mismatching react-router-dom version between Host and Child's package.json dependency....though I find it hard to believe why CORS error would be thrown coz of that...

Comment: Agreed, seems a bit odd as I'd expect each app to be built/run a bit independently from each other.